# PHP equivalent of $array[] in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pass an arbitrary amount of arrays from my javascript to a php file with json through ajax, the problem word is arbitrary, assume following allmost-development-code

```
var arrayContaingAll;

$("li", "#list").each(function()
{
  var a = array( $(".name",this).val(), $(".unit",this).val(), $(".amount", this).val() );
  arrayContainingAll[] = a;
});
```

however, the [] functionality on an array does not work for me, how would i go around implementing such feature?

Yes, i know PHP damaged me thinking that way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arrayContainingAll.push(a); //equavalent in JavaScript to PHP's arrayContainingAll[] = a;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var arrayContaingAll=[];

$("li", "#list").each(function()
{
  var tempArray=[];
  tempArray.push($(".name",this).val());
  tempArray.push($(".unit",this).val());
  tempArray.push($(".amount",this).val());
  arrayContainingAll.push(tempArray);
});

//arrayContaingAll is ready
```

//to optimize ur code you may cache `li` like this inside `each`

```
var li= $(this);
tempArray.push(li.find('class_Name'));
```